# API for linux /sys nodes

Tags: linux, ioctl

Do all nodes in `/sys` (and `/proc`) have an equivalent API? Like an ioctl or a library function. What resource can I use to find those?

---

Context:

I want to enable RFS by setting values in `/proc/sys/net/core/rps_sock_flow_entries` and `/sys/class/net/<iface>/queues/rx-X/rps_flow_cnt;`.

Using those in the terminal or a shell script is ok but it feels wrong in a C program.

Comment: This seems a useful little script to play around - https://gist.github.com/fjrti/69805cf4e4237aa895eeba568ea2ca78#file-set_rps-sh

Answer (score 0):

> Do all nodes in /sys

Yes.

> (and /proc) have an equivalent API?

No, but still 99% of them will use POSIX open/read/write operations.

Some of proc entries can be `poll` or `mmap`, some not. Also https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/proc_fs.h#L29 .

> What resource can I use to find those?

Linux Kernel source code and Linux Kernel documentation. Google and internet resources and man pages.